# C# ASP.NET using TimeSpan to restrict hours to log into a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, authentication

All,

When a customer logs into my website, I want to show how much time is remaining until the log in link times out.

Using the TimeSpan structure in C#, for some reason, I cannot figure out how to do this task:

```
TimeSpan diff = (DateTime.Now - orderDate   );
```

When the customer logs in, I want to show the customer how much time he/she has remaining to log in... "you have 3 hours 33 minutes until this link times out." ... "You have 2 hours 25 minutes until this link times out" etc.

Once 4 hours is hit, when the customer logs in, I am going to redirect him/her to a sorry... the link has timed out page.

So some Psudo code might be...

```
if (diff.Hours >= 4)
{
response.redirect("log_in_timed_out.aspx");
}
else
{
lblTimeRemaining.Text = "You have " + diff.Hours + " hours and " + diff.Minutes + " minutes remaining until the link times out.";
}
```

This psudo code makes the hours and minutes count up instead of down to 0. So I log in and it says you have 1 hours 33 minutes, 2 hours 12 minutes, etc. because the TimeSpan is giving me the difference between the two dates. And I want it to count down to 0 such as 3 hours 23 minutes, 2 hours 15 minutes, 1 hour 5 minutes, etc.

How can I show how much time is remaining to the customer each time he/she logs in using the TimeSpan structure and have it count down to 0?

thanks for any feedback.

Comment: You should use `UtcNow` instead of `Now`, else you'll get angry customers who only got 3h due to DST switching.

Comment: What's your problem? Your pseudo-code looks fine to me. Personally I wouldn't redirect them, but rather show the error in place.

Comment: I want the lblTimeRemaining to show time counting down. For example, 4 hours 00 minutes, 3 hours 15 minutes, 2 hours 13 minutes, etc. If I use the psudo code... it counts up, not down. So this line:

Comment: Sorry committed prior to finishing the comment... lblTimeRemaining.Text = "You have " + diff.Hours + " hours and " + diff.Minutes + " minutes remaining until the link times out."; Is actually counting up the hours/ minutes since it is showing the difference between the times. So I log in and it says you have 1 hour 23 minutes, 2 hours 15 minutes, 3 hours 45 minutes, etc. Since that TimeSpan structure is giving the difference between the two times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend keeping all internal `DateTime`s in `UTC`, and only convert to local times for display. So I use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` and assume `orderTime` is in UTC as well.

I first compute the time at which the link expires, and then how much time remains until then.

```
DateTime expirationTime = orderTime.AddHours(4);
TimeSpan timeRemaining = expirationTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
if(timeRemaining<TimeSpan.Zero)
  Error("Expired");
else
  Write("Remaining {0} hours {1} minutes",timeRemaining.Hours, timeRemaining.Minutes);
```

For better testability it can be useful not to call `DateTime.UtcNow`/`.Now` inline, but to pass in the value. But since I don't know your surrounding code and architecture, I went with the simple approach.

Comment: thanks! Exactly what I was after and thanks for pointing out the <TimeSpan.Zero.

Comment: For others reading... the one line that reads TimeSpan timeRemaining = orderTime - DateTime.UtcNow; Is not correct... it should read TimeSpan timeRemaining = expirationTime - DateTime.UtcNow; - it should use expirationTime and not orderTime.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, since you know that the limit is 4 hours, add the 4 hours to orderDate and then just take the difference between UtcNow, and the condition should change to.....

```
TimeSpan diff = (orderDate.AddHours(4) - DateTime.UtcNow);


if (diff < TimeSpan.Zero)
{
    response.redirect("log_in_timed_out.aspx");
}
else
{
    lblTimeRemaining.Text = "You have " + diff.Hours + " hours and " + diff.Minutes + " minutes remaining until the link times out.";
}
```

Comment: `diff.Hours <= -1` doesn't work. `diff.Hours` will equal `0` for an hour after expiration.

Comment: true... then diff.Minutes <= -1. But I see much better your TimeSpan.Zero

Comment: `diff.Minutes <= -1` -- Then the link will occasionally become functional again for a minute, because it's `0` for one minute every hour. You could use `TotalSeconds` instead, or just keep working with `TimeSpan`s.