# How to test that 8:00 PM is valid prior to 12:00 AM?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, utc

All,

I recently [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966507/c-sharp-asp-net-using-timespan-to-restrict-hours-to-log-into-a-website) on restricting a users log in to 4 hours and got great feedback/answers.

But I have hit a scenario that has me stumped.

The customer has from 8:00 PM up through 12:00 AM of the next day to log in - 4 hours total. However, my code is seeing 8:00 PM as time passed rather than 8:00 PM being time before 12:00 AM.

How can I get the system to see 8:00 PM as time that has not yet passed before 12:00 AM of the next day?

Here is my code using a 12 hour clock with AM and PM - not UTC or 24 hour clock:

```
var orderTime = Convert.ToDateTime(orderDate); // 8:00 PM
var expirationTime = orderTime.AddHours(4); // 12:00 AM of the next day

// timeRemaining should be 4 hours but is 0
// DateTime.Now is 8:00 PM of the current day
// so timeRemaining = 8:00 PM - 12:00 AM (should be 4 hours) 
var timeRemaining = expirationTime - DateTime.Now;

// should be greater than 0 since timeRemaining is actually 4 hours (8:00 PM up to 12:00 AM of next day)
// but fails seeing it as passed
if (timeRemaining < TimeSpan.Zero)                     
    Response.Redirect("TimedOut.aspx");
```

How can I get this scenario to be valid? That is, the system to see 8:00 PM as time that has not yet passed before 12:00 AM of the next day?

thanks for any help!

Comment: I think the only way to get around this issue is to also include the date when both stamping the session and when validating if/when it should end.

Comment: @Cole Johnson - I am a blind computer programmer and have difficulty using some of the features on the website here - one of which is formatting code. Since you pointed out I need to learn how to format, how about you offer me some instructions on how to format the code using the keyboard and not the mouse?

Comment: @Soner Gönül - thank you so much for formatting my code. I seen you do that on my last question too... much appreciated.

Comment: If you use 11:59pm instead of 12:00am you don't need the date.

Comment: Is this your whole code? It obviously works as expected or at least I can't seem to find a scenario when it wouldn't.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi - Can you confirm this thought of mine? orderTime.AddHours(4)  is only adding 4 hours and taking the time to 12:00 AM but it is leaving the date part of the DateTime struct the same - the prior day. It is not moving the Date part up to the next day. If it did, I think my test would pass. So if adding 4 hours takes the time to 12:00 AM - how then can I make sure the date part of the DateTime struct bumps up to the next day? I thought this would happen automatically based on the time going to 12:00 AM?

Comment: @walther yes, this is all my code dealing with this time test scenario. I think I may have figured it out... see my prior comment to Elad Lachmi. Do you have any feedback after reading that comment? thanks!

Comment: Frekster, I'm sorry, I can't replicate your code. When I try it, it gives me correct results no matter what.. Only thing that comes into my mind is to check the variable `orderDate`. If that doesn't contain `year`, `month` and `day` parts, **maybe** it could fail. I can't see you getting the variable nowhere in the code.

Comment: @AlinaB., this code works for me perfectly with or without ToUniversalTime, but who knows..

Comment: @walther - let me see if I can clarify some more using a fake date/time scenario. 1/1/2013 8:00 PM, add 4 hours, I thought would take it to 1/2/2013 12:00 AM. But the .AddHours(4) previously mentioned I think is only adjusting the hours part of the DateTime struct and is not automatically bumping the date to the next day. So 1/1/2013 8:00 PM .AddHours(4) = 1/1/2013 12:00 AM - time has passed! I think this may be what is going on here?

Comment: @walther  assume that I am using a 12 hour time with AM and PM and not UTC or 24 hour time.

Comment: Please see my answer with an example what's working for me. Please try it in a separate console project first to ensure there isn't something else interfering. Btw, about that code formatting - this topic shows some nice examples of formatting using a keyboard - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks See if it helps you at least a bit :)

Comment: @walther  thanks for the code formatting link... perfect! Said that I can highlight the code and press ctrl+k on the keyboard to format my code. Thanks for your time in posting the answer... am trying it in a console app now.

Comment: @walther - yes, the code works fine. There has to be something dumb on my end that I am missing.  Frx the db DateTime field is in 24 hour time format and my local C# code I have in 12 hour format and my thinking on the calculations was not correct. That shouldn't matter but just trying to figure out where I lost my mind. :) What is the significance of the .ToUniversalDateTime() option? Does it force the date struct to use the 24 hour time format regardless of what the sql server db is returning to me?

Comment: `The Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is equal to the local time minus the UTC offset. For more information about the UTC offset, see TimeZone.GetUtcOffset. The conversion also takes into account the daylight saving time rule that applies to the time represented by the current DateTime object.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine for me. I believe it's some code you're not showing here or for some other dumb reason. I was testing with this code (and many variations of it):

```
// force the date format to be 12hour like in US
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013 7:00 PM").ToUniversalTime();
DateTime end = start.AddHours(5); // returns 1/2/2013 12:00:00 AM as it should

Console.WriteLine(end - start); // 05:00:00
Console.WriteLine((end - start) > TimeSpan.Zero); // True
```